# What's the "geometry" in "geometric multiplicity"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, math-history

The *[geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_and_geometric_multiplicities)* of an eigenvalue is defined as the dimension of the associated eigenspace, i.e. number of linearly independent eigenvectors with that eigenvalue.

Here are my **questions**:

- Where is the name "geometric multiplicity" from in math history?
- Is there any thing in geometry related to this concept? Does it only mean the number of linearly independent eigenvectors with that eigenvalue one can "draw" as the definition says?

Comment: Well, an eigenspace is a vector subspace, so if the geometric multiplicity is 1 then it is a line through the origin, if it is 2 then it is a plane through the origin, etc. This is just a wild guess, but it seems plausible that the name might come from this interpretation.

Comment: The term seems self-explanatory.  If you're talking about the dimension of a space, you're talking about geometry.

Comment: Would be cool to find the historic roots of this term, that is: when was it first used? Great question. From OED:  "3. Math. The number of times, for a given root a, that (x − a) occurs as a factor of f(x) (or its Taylor expansion about the point x = a). 1841   J. J. Sylvester in London, Edinb., & Dublin Philos. Mag. 18 136,   I use the word multiplicity to denote a number, and distinguish between the total and partial multiplicities of the roots of an algebraic equation." **But when was "geometric multiplicity" first used?** It's not in the OED.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Bruno is essentially correct.  It's important to see that *geometric* multiplicity is meant to be distinguished from *algebraic* multiplicity of eigenvalues, the latter being the total number of times an eigenvalue occurs as a root of the characteristic equation.  An analogy can be made with roots of any polynomial.  For example, $x^2 + 2x + 1$ has a single root $-1$ of multiplicity 2.  Algebraically, there are always two roots for a quadratic (at least over $\mathbb{C}$), and in this case, those roots are $-1$ and $-1$.  But (geometrically) there is only one $x$-intercept for the function $y = x^2 + 2x + 1$.

Comment: Also, to answer your second question, the "geometry" in geometric multiplicity simply refers to the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to that eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Given a linear map $L:V \to V$; $V$, $W$ vector spaces, the eigenspace $E$ associated with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is that subspace of $V$ where $L$ acts as a scalar, i.e., $L$ acts by stretching vectors. The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the dimension of the subspace of $V$ (in the domain) where $T$ acts as a scalar, with scaling coefficient $\lambda$, i.e., $T$ when restricted to the eigenspace is a map given by $T(v)=\lambda v$.

Maybe the clearest example is that given by the identity map $I:V \to V$, $I(v)=v$, where $V$ is $n$-dimensional ($n < \infty$), with associated matrix the identity matrix. Here, the only eigenvalue is $1$, and you can easily see, e.g, by looking at the associated matrix ($M-\lambda I:=(I-1I)=0$ that the geometric multiplicity is $n$; this means that the identity acts on the whole of $V$ by scaling by $1$. Substituting the identity matrix for a scalar matrix (i.e. $a_{ii}=c$; $a_{ij}=0$; $i\neq j$) illustrates the same point, e.g., if our matrix is the matrix ($a_{ij}:a_{ii}=2$; $a_{ij}=0$ if $i \neq j$ ) then $M$ acts like a scalar for every vector.

At the other extreme, if our matrix represents a linear transformation of a rotation by an angle $\theta \neq 0, \neq 2n\pi$, then the eigenspace is $0$-dimensional, since each point will be sent to another point with the same radius (because it will send a point $p$ in a circle $C$ to another point $p'$ in the same circle), and no point will be rotated into itself. The eigenspace would then be $0$-dimensional, since only the dimension-zero subspace will be sent to itself.